# Automatic scaling data type in C++?

Tags: c++

Is there a way to use a generic datatype in C++ that automatically scales to the type of number used? Like it only uses a short int if that's all the number needs to be stored, changes to a long long if you use a big number, etc?

Comment: An `enum` does that, but why do you need such a thing?

Comment: Aren't larger data types slower/bulkier? It seems like it'd be effective to only use what you need for maximal speed.

Comment: Not really, for example a short or a bool might  be promoted to an int just because the registers hold 32-bit types.

Comment: C++ doesn't have such embedded types. But its possible to write custom class that will be expanded when is needed

Comment: Unless you need tremendously large ints (like 256 bits), the overhead of maintaining the size is probably going to be worse than just using the largest size.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for speed, i don't recommend you a scalable variable usage in C++ but if you need flexibility instead of speed, here is your possible solution.

http://gmplib.org/

Comment: GMP is fast, but I would say not so easy at usage, as it is for C. I do not see good C++ wraper already.